# show output of python file on console

Tags: linux

in console I run `pgrep python | xargs ps` and it shows me 2 python scripts running on background. 
But how can I show output of each script on console?

P.S. I just want to see last printed outputs from scripts to know if scripts are running fine or printed some exceptions or my messages.

Additional subquetion - What in case, when scripts are automatically executed via rc.local on boot? Is there any way how to get screen for these scripts?

Comment: Where is the output going now?

Comment: now it is standard console, I mean when I run the script from command line, it shows me output. But when I log off from ssh and then log in again (script is running from previous), then I dont see output anymore for that script.

Comment: How do you run the scripts?

Comment: An answer is "use `screen`" but I'm sure there's a duplicate out there with some proper instructions. Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22781/how-to-recover-a-shell-after-a-disconnection

Comment: And what in case, when scripts are automatically executed via rc.local on boot? Is there any way how to get screen for these scripts?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use **screen** or **tmux**. Both allow you to disconnect from a running session while maintaining the terminals your scripts are using for output. To use either, simply type **tmux** (or **screen**) when you connect with ssh (you might have to install *tmux* first but most distributions have these tools available in default repositories) and then run your script as usual. If you disconnect, run **tmux attach** again after reconnecting with ssh to restore your previous session.

Comment: I didn't know this. Thanks looks nice. But what in case, when scripts are automatically executed via rc.local on boot? Is there any way how to get screen for these scripts?

Comment: If scripts are executed outside of interactive sessions (rc.local, cron, running as a daemon, etc.) you should redirect their output to a file or implement proper logging.